# How to populate a textbox by clicked a row in a jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid-asp.net

[image]

Requirement:

1) I want to populate a textbox with data (e.g. Amount: 600.0) when a row in the above jqGrid is clicked.

Can someone direct me to a tutorial for this ?

Resources looked at:

- [Demos -- Trirand jqGrid for ASP.NET](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx)
- [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event along with the `getCell` or `getRowData` methods:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    ....
    onSelectRow: function(id) {
        var amount = $('#grid').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'Amount');
        $('#id_of_some_text_box').val(amount);
    },
    ....
});
```